# MongoDB - Database vs Collection memory-wise

Tags: mongodb

Lets say for example i need to have 5 collections, each collection is about 10GB.
What is the difference in performance, with emphasis on memory usage, between assigning each said collection to a database, versus having all of these collections in the same database?

Also, in this scenario, whats the difference between `MMAPv1` storage engine and `TigerWire`?

Comment: Educated guess: there wouldn't be any non-negligible difference in performance/memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, database is just a namespace. All data is stored in collections. This is true for both MMAPv1 (deprecated in 4.0, not available anymore in the upcoming 4.2) and WiredTiger storage engine.

Due to this, separating your data into separate databases or not doesn't make any difference storage-wise, unless you specify [`directoryPerDB` setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB), which simply put collections related to a database in their own folder.